# onFormSubmit(e) I need to sum 4 columns and output to a PDF

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

This seems like a simple problem, add 4 Form Event columns(Cost 1, Cost 2, Cost 3, Cost 4) and output calculated 'Total' to a PDF via email utilizing a template.  I have no problem getting the Event(e) data to the template and sent via email but cannot get the total.  I've tried many different Google App Scripts from this site to no avail.  Currently, I have a separate sheet called 'Total' and created an array that captures the Event data columns and displays exactly what I want but I cannot get it to the template, problem code may be on line 20.  I've included links to the template as well as the Spreadsheet and the Google App Script

```
// Get template from Google Docs and name it
  var docTemplate = "1Ti1n71wpA-U5X9yLqSIfLC9VXqcxOGGsZQhYq0ZwJX4";  // *** replace with your template ID ***
  var docName     = "Calculate the total";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) { 

    var name = "Rick"
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Total');   //Get 'Total' sheet
    var row = sheet.getLastRow();             //Get 'Total' last row


//Get information from form and set as variables
  var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm");
  var email_address = "MyEmail address";
  var cost1 = e.values[1];
  var cost2 = e.values[2];
  var cost3 = e.values[3];
  var cost4 = e.values[4];
  var total = sheet.getRange(row, [1]).getValue();  //Is this the problem?




//  Logger.log(e.namedValues);

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Documents ID
   var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById (docTemplate)
              .makeCopy(docName + ' for '+ name)
              .getId();

// Open the temporary document
   var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

// Get the documents body section
   var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template  
   copyBody.replaceText('<<name>>', name);
   copyBody.replaceText('<<cost1>>', cost1);
   copyBody.replaceText('<<cost2>>', cost2);
   copyBody.replaceText('<<cost3>>', cost3);
   copyBody.replaceText('<<cost4>>', cost4);
   copyBody.replaceText('<<total>>', total);
   copyBody.replaceText('<<timeStamp>>', todaysDate);

// Save and close the temporary document
   copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
   var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 

// Attach PDF and send the email
   var subject = "Your Total Cost Project Script";
   var body    = name + ", here is the total cost for your project ";
   MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf}); 

// Delete temp file
   DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/144t33X98eZIAH2k5hCA--fFeUzmJCGefKI7lC1EE4Xc/edit?usp=sharing
Template - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ti1n71wpA-U5X9yLqSIfLC9VXqcxOGGsZQhYq0ZwJX4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why cannot you just do this? `var total = cost1 + cost2 +cost3 + cost4 ` instead of `var total = sheet.getRange(row, [1]).getValue();` ?

Comment: I've tried this but the 'Total' output to the PDF file is concatenated, it just put the (e) values and did not sum.

Comment: Use [`parseint()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to convert your strings into number.. you will have convert each cost value into a integer.. like so, `var cost1 = parseInt(e.values[1])` and so forth. Note, if your values are not strictly a integer you can use [`parsedFloat`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) instead

Comment: That works perfect!

Comment: Consider answering your own question below, thank you!

Comment: Here is modified working code.  (e.values[x]) returns a string so..parseInt converts to a number so processing can take place. This number conversion only uses whole numbers. Thanks to @Jack Brown
  var cost1 = parseInt (e.values[1]); //parseInt converts (e.values[x]) from string to number for var costx
  var cost2 = parseInt (e.values[2]);
  var cost3 = parseInt (e.values[3]);
  var cost4 = parseInt (e.values[4]);
  var total = cost1 + cost2 + cost3 + cost4;